# Different labels for one \align environment

Tags: align

I would like to know please, how can I label multiple equations in one `align` environment.
Below is a snippet of my code.

```
\begin{align}
\mathrm{R}_{x_3} &= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
       \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) & 0 \\
       \sin(\phi) &  \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} \label{R}\label{Rx3} \\
\mathrm{\textbf{T}_{inf}} &= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \dfrac{\mathrm{r}}{\mathrm{d_{r}}\rho} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & \left(1+\left(\alpha\mathrm{r}\right)^2\right)
          \dfrac{\mathrm{d_{r}}\rho}{\mathrm{r}} & \alpha\mathrm{d_{r}r} \\
      0 & \alpha\mathrm{d_{r}r} & \dfrac{\mathrm{d_{r}r}}{\rho}
    \end{pmatrix} \\
\label{Tinf}
\end{align}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can put a `\label` in every line. Right now you are putting two in the first one, none in the second, and one in the empty third line.

Comment: before the "\\" or after?

Comment: I did it before the "\\", thank you! Also thank you for the remark (the two labels). I did not pay attention to that :)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "label multiple equations". E.g., do you want to assign a single equation number to several equations? Or is it something else you're after? Please be specific.

Comment: @Mico, yes I wanted to assign multiple labels in the same align environment for each equation defined. I did as campa told me, and just inserted label at the end of each line and it worked :D

Comment: Off-topic: I think you should replace `\mathrm{\textbf{T}_{inf}}` with `\mathbf{T}_{\inf}`. It would certainly make input parsing easier.

Comment: don't think of it as "before or after `\\ `" think of it as "in the equation that you want to label"